# Confusion on Absolute Temperature Scales used in solving Carnot Cycle problems

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, carnot-cycle, absolute-units

I have a Carnot Cycle problem where the temperatures of the hot and cold reservoirs are given in Celsius and I'm asked to solve for the cycle efficiency. Of course, My first step is to convert Celsius to an absolute temperature scale like Kelvin before inputting the values to the formula. My question is that would I arrive to the same answer if I converted Celsius to Rankine for checking purposes?

Comment: *My question is that would I arrive to the same answer if I converted Celsius to Rankine for checking purposes?* It depends on the nature of the question but the value of $T_1/T_2$ is the same when using K or $^\circ$R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can answer your question by doing the calculation yourself, first in Kelvin then in Rankine. (The answer is Yes.)